# Is there a special meaning for "this has to go"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

One of my friends told me "when you wanna say something is obsolete, you can say..well this has to go". Is this true?

Then if I'd like to dump my t-shirt, can I say "this t-shirt has to go"?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This idiom has a humorous shade to it for me.

Comment: Thank you, Chaudhary. By the way, Cargill said it has a strong imperative sense, but you said it has different shade to it. Then, do you mean it depends on the situation I speak to someone?

Comment: True, it most certainly depends on the context. In the example Cargill mentioned, it sounds imperative. It would be funny when you tell your partner this pointing to the bed you rendered unusable after last night.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. And Should I have said "thank you, Mr.Chaudhary"? Or is it ok just to say "Thank you, somebody's family name"? If I make a mistake, please pardon me.

Comment: Including the `Mr.` would make it very formal, not required here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a pretty ordinary thing to say: an idiom.

If you wish to spice it up, you could add, "... where the woodbine twineth."

Comment: Thank you, Ricky. By the way, what's the "where the woodbine twineth"? Is it a kind of rhyme or something, less meaningful things? I can't understand the meaning of it with "something has to go".

Comment: @9ex9: It means it has to go to t-shirt Paradise. It's where t-shirts go when they die. It's a paraphrase of a few lines from Shakespeare. "Midsummer Night's Dream" if I recollect aright.

Comment: Wow, it's so funny idiom. :) Going to T-shirt Paradise....haha. I appreciate your helpful explanation.

Answer (score 2):

It also has a strong imperative sense (also as idiom).  Someone in authority, or with special knowledge, might use it.  So a designer could walk through an office they have been asked to renovate, and say "This purple wall has to go!", and similar.

Comment: Thank you, Cargill. You mean I have to be careful to use this "has to go" sentence not to be heard arrogant or aggressive. Do you think it would be still heard imperative even though I say this "has to go" thing softly? Is it clear? It is a little bit hard to say in English.

Comment: I certainly agree that it can be - and is - often used humorously.  However the phrase usually means that the speaker has a pretty emphatic opinion about the need for something to be gone, and therefore if used carelessly can hurt someone's feelings, or worse.  A junior employee (say) might have put huge effort into getting that purple wall in the office!

Comment: I appreciate your kind explanation. But there's one more question. I cannot understand "the purple wall" you gave me as an example. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: No bother.  It was just an example for illustrative purposes, since design features like "purple walls" are/were popular at certain times and to certain tastes. When a new interior designer is engaged, the stereotype would often see them shudder at the "purple wall" (or orange curtains, bright green carpet, etc), and say "It has to go!".

Comment: Now I got it. Thanks a lot again, Cargill. :) Have a nice Christmas, it might be too early to say this..haha